# Passing environment variable as a pipeline parameter to Jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have a shared Jenkins library that has my pipeline for Jenkinsfile. The library is structured as follows:

*myPipeline.groovy* file

```
def call(body) {
    def params= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = params
    body()

    pipeline {
        // My entire pipeline is here
        // Demo stage
        stage("Something"){
          steps{
            script{
              projectName = params.name
            }
          }
        }

    }
}
```

And my Jenkinsfile is as follows:

*Jenkinsfile*

```
@Library("some-shared-lib") _
myPipeline{
    name = "Some name"
}
```

Now, I would like to replace `"Some name"` string with `"env.JOB_NAME"` command. Normally in Jenkinsfile, I would use `name = "${env.JOB_NAME}"` to get the info, but because I am using my shared library instead, it failed to work. Error message is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'JOB_NAME' on null object
```

I tried to play around with brackets and other notation but never got it to work. I think that I incorrectly pass a parameter. I would like Jenkinsfile to assign `"${env.JOB_NAME}"` to `projectName` variable, once library runs the pipeline that I am calling (via `myPipeline{}` command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this in `myPipeline.groovy`:

```
def call(body) {
    def params= [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = params
    body()

    pipeline {
        // My entire pipeline is here
        // Demo stage
        stage("Something"){
          steps{
            script{
              projectName = "${env.JOB_NAME}"
            }
          }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be the best candidate but I really would like to have ```env.JOB_NAME``` defined in my Jenkinsfile. Wonder if it is possible?